# Is it possible to return lambdas in a function?

Tags: apl, gnu-apl

Consider the following function, which should return a function that adds two to any given argument:

```
∇r←addtwo
  r←{⍵+2}
∇
```

This code loads without any errors, but I just cannot use the return value without causing errors.

```
      addtwo ⍝ doesn't cause errors
      addtwo 1
VALUE ERROR
      addtwo 1
      ^
      x←addtwo
VALUE ERROR
      x←addtwo
      ^
```

I am using `GNU-APL 1.8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Dyalog APL](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Dyalog_APL) is the only implementation allowing this. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FHe9GjtgmJKSkl5flcCgogTvWj3q3aRrVcQLn//yEyCo965yqk5KcW56mXKCQnlhanKqQWFeUXFXNB5Q25KhDGVCgYAgA)

Even though this could work, it isn't the normal APL way of doing things. You may want to look into writing [your own operator](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Defined_function#Operators) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The usual work-around for what you intend to do is to return a string from the function and execute (⍎) the string:

```
      ∇Z←FOO
[1] ⍝ return a string that can be ⍎'ed····
[2] Z←'{⍵+2}'
[3] ∇

      ⍎FOO,⍕42
44
```

Comment: This is useful for constant dfns, but when I want to use it as a closure and capture variables at runtime, it will become complicated.

Comment: The constants were only used to simplify the example. Apart from that, using closures in APL is, IMHO, like writing web pages in FORTRAN - it is possible but probably the wrong way of using the language.